# Playing drm encrypted wmv files in Linux

Tags: multimedia

How do I play drm encrypted wmv files in Ubuntu? If it is possible, how do I do it. I've tried playing it with vlc and MPlayer media player but does not work. I am getting a scrambled picture when I play it through vlc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ***only*** way is through Windows Media Player. This leaves you with three options:

1. Install Windows Media Player 11 on Wine.
2. Install XP in virtualbox and Windows Media Player 11 on XP.
3. Dual boot.